# Error validating a string in a textbox in case of blank spaces at the end of the string

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have the following textbox with its validator. A user can enter up to 300 characters only. The validator works well if there are no blank spaces or breaks at the end of the string. If a user enters blank spaces at the end by mistake, the validator is fired, even if the number of characters is below 300. Any hint how to solve this problem?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     ID="TipsValidator" 
     runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="Max 300 characters"
     ControlToValidate="TipsTextBox"
     Display="Static" 
     ValidationExpression=".{0,300}"
     ValidationGroup="UpdateGroup"
     ForeColor="Red" />

<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Tips") %>' runat="server" ID="TipsTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6" Columns="10" />
```

Comment: If the goal is to ensure that a max length of 300 characters is applied, would the [MaxLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the textbox not work? Rather than resorting to a regex, let the textbox control limit the amount of text that can be entered.

Comment: The MaxLength doesn't work either...

Comment: In what way does that not work? Are you able to enter more than 300 characters into the textbox?

Comment: No I can't enter more than 300 characters but if a user copies a text from a word processor and insert it in the textbox (multiline) with carriage return at the end of the box and click save, the text is not saved in the database. It's saved only if the carriage return is deleted. It only happens with the multiline textbox...

Comment: Take a step back - what is the value of `TipsTextBox` when it is posted back to the web form?